# unable to locate any package while installing from terminal

Tags: software-installation

I was mashing with my computer and it start showing this error, while installing any software(sl, git, gvim,etc) it shows

```
E: Unable to locate package (package_name)
```

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. When you say you were "mashing" with your computer, what do you mean ? What was the last thing/file you modified that made the system go wrong ? What do you use to install software (`apt-get`, `synaptic`, ... )? Did you play around with your `sources.list` ? What happens when you run `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: I'm using sudo apt-get install

Comment: No,I was using ubuntu and got the same problem so I reinstall ubuntu and again it is showing the same message

Comment: Could you address my other questions and edit your original post acordingly ? More precisely, could you tell us what `apt-get update` returns, and the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: Thanx man sudo apt-get update works i was not thinking of using sudo apt-get update because it was not working on my previous ubuntu but now it works..

Comment: You need to update your package list every now and then ;) Glad it worked for you. In the future, when you en counter a pb concerning versionning/packages not found, try `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` before anything else

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh install, you always need to perform a `sudo apt-get update` to update your packages list using the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files.

This updates the package list and helps apt know from where each package mention in `sudo apt-get install <package_name>` should be fetched.

So before you do a `sudo apt-get install <package_name>` on fresh default installation(default in the sense it is not a remastered installation- which may or may not necessarily require an update), you *need* to do a `sudo apt-get update`.